# Замена значений в массивах двумерного массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы

Допустим у меня есть двумерный массив ArrOfArr.

Он выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно заменить ' ' (пробелы) допустим на другой символ, аналогично тому, как работает инструмент “Заливка” в графических редакторах, что бы получилось что- то вроде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это осуществить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Возможно, я недостаточно компетентен, я не могу словами выразить суть вопроса и понятно изложить задачу. На картинках у меня вроде бы это получилось. И для меня очень важно решить эту проблему.

Comment: у вас всё отлично выражено именно словами. только эти слова вы написали **на** картинке. вместо того, чтобы вписать их текстом непосредственно **в** вопрос.

Comment: Я такой вопрос уже вчера видел. Не надо спрашивать одно и то же несколько раз.

Comment: @Qwertiy я удалил вчерашнюю тему, мне никто не ответил, только очень раскритиковали оформление. Ребята поймите пожалуйста, я джун, я на этом форуме в первый раз, я постарался максимально понятно изложить вопрос, меньше токсичности я очень вас прошу, пожалуйста. Лучше помогите решить эту проблему.

Comment: Править надо и на вопросы отвечать. Я тебя там спросил, а ты мне так и не ответил ;) А по теме: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/116398/). Или пишется на основе обычного dfs, но с закраской по строкам оптимальнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я понимаю, что такое заливка. У меня есть написанное своими руками большое приложение по созданию анимаций, своего рода граффический редактор, и там есть заливка. Дело в том, что тут вовсе иная логика, которуя я пока не могу реализовать. Тут у меня просто есть массив arrOfArr. В нем есть массивы строк, с разными значениями. И мне нужно заменить эти значения. arrOfArr.fill('o', (x), (y)  (где Х индекс массива, с какого заменить, Y по какой) тут не подойдут, поэтому я и упомянул заливку в качестве аналогии. В целом, я нормально на этот раз вопрос сформулировал в шапке?

Comment: По тексту вопроса тебе нужна именно заливка. Если она тебе не подходит, то нет. А fill тут вообще никаким боком.

Comment: @Qwertiy заливка работает для координат. Мне нужно использовать строчные символы, заполнять ими свой массив. Это просто строки, не рисунок. Вон у меня на картинке сверху этот массив показан.

Comment: @concrete, алгоритм тот же самый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто - перебираем соседние точки рекурсивной функцией, уже пройденные игнорируем...

> Обратите внимание, для эстетического удовольствия я уменьшаю пользовательский ввод на 1, чтобы не считать с нуля в UI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Omg</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre contenteditable>
    </pre>
    <p>X: <input type="number" value="3"></p>
    <p>Y: <input type="number" value="5"></p>
    <button>Fill</button>
    <script>
      (function() {
        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        const content = document.querySelector('pre');
        const area = [
          "110000000",
          "100010000",
          "001111100",
          "000010000",
          "000000000"
        ].map((s) => s.split(''));

        const inRange = (x,y) => {
          if (x < 0 || x > area.length) {
            return false;
          } else if (y < 0 || y > area[0].length) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }

        const border = (x,y) => [
          [x-1,y-1], 
          [x,y],
          [x-1,y+1],
          [x,y+1],
          [x,y-1],
          [x+1,y],
          [x+1,y+1],
          [x+1,y-1]
        ].filter(([x, y]) => inRange(x,y));

        const print = () => content.innerText = area.map((line) => line.join('')).join("\n");

        button.onclick = () => {
          const x = document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value - 1;
          const y = document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value - 1;

          const ignore = new Set();

          const fill = (x, y) => {
            const pos = `${x}:${y}`;
            if (ignore.has(pos)) {
              return;
            } else if (area[x][y] == 1) {
              ignore.add(pos);
              area[x][y] = 0;
              border(x, y).forEach(([x, y]) => fill(x,y));
            } else {
              return;
            }
          }

          fill(x, y);
          print();
        }

        print();

      })();  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Конкретно в данном случае можно обойтись без `ignore`, так как мы приравниваем новое значение и выходим из цикла, но если нужно просто посчитать точки - будет полезно.

Comment: Решение идеальное, просто супер! Переиспользовать у себя не получается ><

Comment: @concrete Копайте :-) Там просто нужно поковыряться с if (area[x][y] === 1)... А так, если не жалко, пометьте ответ как верный

Comment: Пометил, спасибо Вам огромное ! Я был бы очень признателен, если бы Вы пояснили, почему у меня срабатыввает вся эта структура только для одной координаты?

Comment: понял, что у  меня проблема в выражении border(y, x).forEach(([x, y]) => fill(x, y)); Вы могли бы помочь разобраться? Не думаю, что это займет много времени. В дискорде например, где я бы мог показать экран? Был бы очень благодарен

Comment: @concrete Дискорд не использую, есть скайп live:tripolskypetr

Comment: Большое спасибо! Мне удалось в итоге решить эту задачу!!  ^^,)